# An own function to multiply two matrices in r

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

So i have a task that says:
Make your own function to multiply two matrices ( not by using %*%).

I have tried this but clearly i doesnt work...

```
isacs_funcion<- function (A,B){
      result<- sum(as.vector(A) * as.vector(B)) 
       return(matrix(A,B ))}
```

Can someone help me? Sorry for bad english

Comment: Your function is taking the variables A and B and simply returning them as a matrix. Your result<- sum(as.vector(A) * as.vector(B)) line doesn't do anything because as soon as the function exists, result is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try with a nested `sapply`

```
t(sapply(seq_len(ncol(m1)), function(i) 
    sapply(seq_len(nrow(m2)), function(j) sum(m1[i,] * m2[,j]))))
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,] 1590 1865 2140 2415 2690
 #[2,] 1730 2030 2330 2630 2930
 #[3,] 1870 2195 2520 2845 3170
 #[4,] 2010 2360 2710 3060 3410
 #[5,] 2150 2525 2900 3275 3650
```

which is similar to

```
  m1%*%m2
  #    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  #[1,] 1590 1865 2140 2415 2690
  #[2,] 1730 2030 2330 2630 2930
  #[3,] 1870 2195 2520 2845 3170
  #[4,] 2010 2360 2710 3060 3410
  #[5,] 2150 2525 2900 3275 3650
```

#### data

```
 m1 <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5)
 m2 <- matrix(26:50, 5, 5)
```